# Sorting JSON by entry values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I am trying to sort through some JSON to create a list of the data where only certain rows are shown. I have some code that displays the data the way I want to display it, it just isn't sorted the way I want it. Here is the working code for the pre-sorted data:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css"> 
.items {display:table;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;border-spacing:5px;}
.items li {display:table-row;-webkit-border-radius:10px;-moz-border-radius:10px;border-radius:10px;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:5px;margin:0 0 10px 0;}
.items li img {display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;width:160px;height:120px;}
.items li span.meta {display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;margin:0;padding:0 0 0 5px;font-size:6;}
.items li {margin:0 0 5px 0;}
</style>
<button onclick="mySearch()" type="button">Search</button>
<button onclick="myErase()" type="button">Clear Results</button>
<div id="home-list"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function mySearch() {   
$('.items').remove();

//source file is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2   

$(function listHomes() {    

$.getJSON( "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=?",

//this is the data that I wish to sort
function (data) {

    $('div#home-list').append('<ul class="items"></ul>');

    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i,entry) { 

        var item = '<span style="display:none">' + entry.id.$t + '</span>'; 

        item += '<img src="http://img.paragonrels.com/ParagonImages/Listings/P2/CGMLS/' + entry.gsx$mls.$t + '/0/960/720/4d8fbda25ff383c57b907de4c08a8677/CGMLS' + entry.gsx$mls.$t + '.JPG"/>';

        item += '<span class="meta"><a href="http://www.bevhicksrealtor.com/home/search-my-listings/' + entry.gsx$mls.$t + '"><font size="3"><b>' + entry.title.$t + '</b></font></a>'; 

        item += '<br/>City: ' + entry.gsx$city.$t;  

                    item += '<br/>Bedrooms: ' + entry.gsx$beds.$t;  

        if (entry.gsx$subdivision.$t) { 

            item += '<br/>Description: ' + entry.gsx$subdivision.$t;    
        }   
        $('.items').append('<li>' + item + '</span></li>'); 

        });
    });
});
};
function myErase() {
$('.items').remove();
};
</script>
```

Here is the JSON

```
// API callback
JSONP({"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/","xmlns$gsx":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended","id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values"},"updated":{"$t":"2015-01-08T04:27:29.693Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Source Page"},"link":[{"rel":"alternate","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/pubhtml"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values?alt\u003djson-in-script"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"joshuam.hess"},"email":{"$t":"joshuam.hess@yourkickstart.org"}}],"openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":"4"},"openSearch$startIndex":{"$t":"1"},"entry":[{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values/cokwr"},"updated":{"$t":"2015-01-08T04:27:29.693Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"303 Tarpon Trace \u003cbr\u003eByron, GA 31008"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"mls: 122445, state: GA, county: Bibb County, city: Macon, subdivision: None, high: Northside, beds: 4, baths: 3, price: 250000, cars: 3"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values/cokwr"}],"gsx$address":{"$t":"303 Tarpon Trace \u003cbr\u003eByron, GA 31008"},"gsx$mls":{"$t":"122445"},"gsx$state":{"$t":"GA"},"gsx$county":{"$t":"Bibb County"},"gsx$city":{"$t":"Macon"},"gsx$subdivision":{"$t":"None"},"gsx$high":{"$t":"Northside"},"gsx$beds":{"$t":"4"},"gsx$baths":{"$t":"3"},"gsx$price":{"$t":"250000"},"gsx$cars":{"$t":"3"}},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values/cpzh4"},"updated":{"$t":"2015-01-08T04:27:29.693Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"104 Gretta Court \u003cbr\u003eWarner Robins, GA 31088"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"mls: 122444, state: GA, county: Bibb County, city: Macon, subdivision: None, high: Bibb-Westside, beds: 3, baths: 2, price: 200000, cars: 2"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values/cpzh4"}],"gsx$address":{"$t":"104 Gretta Court \u003cbr\u003eWarner Robins, GA 31088"},"gsx$mls":{"$t":"122444"},"gsx$state":{"$t":"GA"},"gsx$county":{"$t":"Bibb County"},"gsx$city":{"$t":"Macon"},"gsx$subdivision":{"$t":"None"},"gsx$high":{"$t":"Bibb-Westside"},"gsx$beds":{"$t":"3"},"gsx$baths":{"$t":"2"},"gsx$price":{"$t":"200000"},"gsx$cars":{"$t":"2"}},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values/cre1l"},"updated":{"$t":"2015-01-08T04:27:29.693Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"112 Derringer Court \u003cbr\u003eByron, GA 31008"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"mls: 120081, state: GA, county: Bibb County, city: Macon, subdivision: Woolfolk, high: See Remarks, beds: 2, baths: 2, price: 150000, cars: 1"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values/cre1l"}],"gsx$address":{"$t":"112 Derringer Court \u003cbr\u003eByron, GA 31008"},"gsx$mls":{"$t":"120081"},"gsx$state":{"$t":"GA"},"gsx$county":{"$t":"Bibb County"},"gsx$city":{"$t":"Macon"},"gsx$subdivision":{"$t":"Woolfolk"},"gsx$high":{"$t":"See Remarks"},"gsx$beds":{"$t":"2"},"gsx$baths":{"$t":"2"},"gsx$price":{"$t":"150000"},"gsx$cars":{"$t":"1"}},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values/chk2m"},"updated":{"$t":"2015-01-08T04:27:29.693Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"105 Kennedy Court \u003cbr\u003eWarner Robins, GA 31093"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"mls: 116141, state: GA, county: Macon County, city: Oglethorpe, subdivision: See Remarks, high: See Remarks, beds: 1, baths: 1, price: 50000, cars: 1"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1z7X-IvfauqyWul4oh_46e471nNt13ZpNhyXSIm_NXKI/ow6ewk2/public/values/chk2m"}],"gsx$address":{"$t":"105 Kennedy Court \u003cbr\u003eWarner Robins, GA 31093"},"gsx$mls":{"$t":"116141"},"gsx$state":{"$t":"GA"},"gsx$county":{"$t":"Macon County"},"gsx$city":{"$t":"Oglethorpe"},"gsx$subdivision":{"$t":"See Remarks"},"gsx$high":{"$t":"See Remarks"},"gsx$beds":{"$t":"1"},"gsx$baths":{"$t":"1"},"gsx$price":{"$t":"50000"},"gsx$cars":{"$t":"1"}}]}});
```

I want to sort the information by several JSON entries (beds, baths, etc.). I have tried dozens of things but have yet to get a result. I even tried sorting the data at the spreadsheet with a query, but I don't think I could get a working JSON response back.

Comment: Please tidy up your code. Strip anything that isn't necessary and point us to where the problems are precisely.

Comment: Annnnd hwat does the JSON look like?

Answer (score 1):

For the sort, I'm going to use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs). I'll also post the same solution in pure JS for those people that want it. The first thing we need to focus on is getting a list of the keys in order. So, let's start with a test object. I'm just gonna throw in some random fields/types:

```
var obj= {  
    test : 5,
    colour : 'red',
    song : 'I Believe In A Thing Called Love',
    profession : 'Singer',
    gender : 'Male',
    languages : {
        array : [ 'French', 'German', 'English' ]
    },
    relationships : {
        'sister' : 'Jasmine',
        'brother' : 'Ryan'
    }
}
```

The first thing we need to do is gain access to a list of the keys inside the object. Fortunately for us, this is pretty simple to do:

```
// Underscore
var keys = _.keys(object);
// → ['test', 'colour', 'song', 'profession', 'gender',     'languages', 'relationships']

// JavaScript
var keys = Object.keys(object);
// → ['test', 'colour', 'song', 'profession', 'gender', 'languages', 'relationships']
```

The first thing you'll notice is that this only gives us top-level keys. This is due to the fact that the inner objects are technically different objects. Were we to call either of the above on the inner object, we would get their keys too.

Ok, so we now have a list of top-level keys in the object. Naturally, the next step is to sort these keys alphabetically, which is also pretty simple. Underscore has a nice method already available for this which makes it pretty easy, but it's also very casual to implement in pure JS.

```
// Underscore
var sortedKeys = _.sortBy(keys, function(key){  
    return object[key]; 
});

// JavaScript
var sortedKeys = keys.sort(function(key1, key2){  
    var val1 = object[key1].toLowerCase();
    var val2 = object[key2].toLowerCase();

    if(val1 < val2 ) return -1;
    if(val1 > val2 ) return 1;
    return 0;
})

// Both → ['colour', 'gender', 'languages', 'profession', 'relationships', 'song', 'test']
```

And finally:

```
var sortedObj = {};

// Underscore
_.each(keys, function(key) {  
    sortedObj[key] = object[key];
});

// JavaScript
for(var index in keys){  
    var key = keys[index];
    sortedObj[key] = object[key];
}

// Resulting object
{
    'colour': 'red',
    'gender': 'Male',
    'languages': {
        'array': [
            'French',
            'German',
            'English'
        ]
    },
    'profession': 'Singer',
    'relationships': {
        'sister': 'Jasmine',
        'brother': 'Ryan'
    },
    'song': 'I Believe In A Thing Called Love',
    'test': 5
}
```

If needed for inner objects as well, we just put in a check for an object type and then recall the code if it's an object:

```
if(typeof object[key] == 'object'){  
    sortedObj[key] = sortObject(object[key]); // sortObj will be the function holding this code
} else {
    sortedObj[key] = object[key];
}
```

[*Source*](http://zackehh.com/sorting-object-recursively-node-jsjavascript/)